# Establish Parent-Child Relationship Using Nested For-Loops between Two Series in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nested

Let me start with the main goal I am trying to achieve. I have a set of numbers that are 14 digits in a database of two sets of categories (Put under 'Hier') Parent or Child  ex 60814703140000: Parent 
if the last 4 digits contain a number ex 60814703140100: Child. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2prr.png)

I am trying to develop an algorithm in Pandas Python that knows how the group the parents with the subsequent children based on the fact that the parent/child shares the  first 10 digits.

My thought process was: extract two vectors from the pandas database:

```
Par=Newdf[Newdf['Hier']=='Parent']
Chi=Newdf[Newdf['Hier']=='Child']
```

And then iterate through the two series using a nested for loop: If the first 10 digits of the element in Par equals the first 10 digits in the element in Chi : then they are of the same family and add them to my list in a way where it gives a list of the associated parent child:
[(60814703140000,60814703140100),(60814702350000,60814702350200),(60814711630000,60814711630500),.....]

```
mat = []

for i in Par['UWI']:
   for j in Chi['UWI']:
      if str(i)[0:9] == str(j)[0:9]:   
        mat.append(str(i),str(j))

mat
```

This code however is giving me an error as I'm having an issue adding multiple items the list at the same time.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-8b0ab9fd7ce5> in <module>()
      7    for j in Chi['UWI']:
      8       if str(i)[0:9] == str(j)[0:9]:
----> 9         mat.append(str(i),str(j))
     10 
     11 mat
```

TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

My question is:

1.What is the correct syntax to add the associated Parent-child relationships

2.The parent child-relationship is not a 1:1 as I may have more than one child for one parent and I would like to incorporate those as well.

3.Is there a better method to do this? For example I know I can use list comprehension but I didn't get that one right due to the added if statement. 
So" How would I use list comprehension with two for-loops and an if statement

4. I appreciate any other criticism or suggestions to improve this code.

Link to dataframe example

Comment: Please post a small sample of your dataframe, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

As it says, it does not like 2 arguments - In this case adding 2 strings onto a list at once.

```
mat.append(str(i))
mat.append(str(j))
```

It could also be worth adding a `try` and an `except` statement in (google it if you are stuck) to make the code more robust - so should some invalid data gets into the database the program won't crash, but do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but how do I make sure that they are joined. If concatenate the two strings, I need to make sure to have them in order. The idea is to group the numebrs as a family.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the comment with a new answer:

I think the way you are looking at it, it would be better to, instead of a list use a dictionary, this way you are able to store 2 items within the same parameters.

```
mat = {}


for i in Par['UWI']:
    for j in Chi['UWI']:
         if str(i)[0:9] == str(j)[0:9]:   
              mat.update({str(i):str(j)})
```

This also makes looking for a perticular person easier, than finding that person and then working out wether it is the person before or after that is the link.